# TeamCity trigger for Github comment on pull request

Tags: android, git, github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have my CI on TeamCity. It currently triggers builds on different events (`Pull Request` creations, merges into `Develop` branch, etc.). However, I was wondering if it is possible to trigger a specific build as a result of writing a specific comment/labelling a `Pull Request`.

**The goal** is to run a set of Automated UI tests when a `Pull Request` has been approved (from a coding correctness point of view) and that branch is ready to be merged into `Develop`. I don't want to run that set of Automated UI tests for every commit on that branch as it takes around 1h to run them and I don't want to run it only after merging that PR so we avoid merging anything that breaks the UI tests into `Develop`.

**The desired flow** would be to write a special comment on that PR such as `run_UI_test` or labelling the PR with a custom label so the tests are executed on CI and the feedback is displayed on the PR on Github.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe TeamCity has any awareness of the comments on Github since the comments themselves aren't stored directly in the branch(es). My assumption is that you have a VCS Root similar to this:

```
+:refs/heads/master
+:refs/heads/develop
+:...
+:refs/pull/*/head
```

It is possible to access the comments of a pull request through the GitHub "Issues API", however, I think this would add unnecessary complexity to your build process and it would obscure how the builds are getting triggered.

My suggestion would be to follow a more tradition CI process and create another layer of "integration" through a new branch. So basically your flow would look like this:

- **master** (merge pull requests for release)
- **integration** (Run UI automation test)
- **develop** (Run basic unit tests and other stuff)

So basically all of your development happens on **develop** or some other "feature" branch. When all basic tests are passing and you are ready to "promote" you could merge into the **integration** branch which will then trigger your UI tests. I also want to point out that this "**integration**" branch could in fact just be "pull requests" and no static branch is actually required depending on how you have your development flow setup.

it's much easier to setup trigger rules and branch filters in TC then it would be to write some custom REST API script to work with the GitHub Issues API.

Comment: That's exactly what I was expecting (that it is not possible). However, I hadn't thought of the "integration" step/branch, which makes a lot of sense and it's the solution I'll go for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Can you mark my answer as "correct" to close the question? Thanks!

Comment: I will, but I'd like to wait a bit more in case other people have other answers that may be even more helpful than yours.

Comment: Ha ha! Fair enough! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve similar functionality by setting up a separate build configuration which utilizes a specific VCS Trigger to run the UI tests. This build configuration would also have different build steps which would include the commands to execute your tests.

For example: In Triggers, you can add a new VCS Trigger with `+:comment=presubmit:**` This would look for any commit message that contains "presubmit" and would trigger your UI test suite to run.

I have seen a few repositories use tools such as https://danger.systems to write custom rules which can look for the text in Github comments and trigger interactions based on the comment.