# trigger TeamCity build when comment on GitHub pull request

Tags: teamcity

I'd like to trigger build by commenting specific message on the pull request, like: "Build again."

I allowed all 'commit', 'PR', and 'comment' things to GitHub-TeamCity hook.

Then I tried with VCS Trigger's 'comment' rule, but no luck.

I'm used to triggering build by comment with Jenkins using this plug-in: https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-pr-comment-build

Is there any plug-in or instructions for TeamCity?

I've looked this SO, and I agree with the chosen answer. However, I found that triggering something via comment is quite handy, and it gives more extensibility such as Slack integration.
[TeamCity trigger for Github comment on pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416556/teamcity-trigger-for-github-comment-on-pull-request)

Comment: okay, what is your problem now? does the last link help you?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor I just want to trigger a build by commenting on the pull request. So that my team triggers build again without dummy commit or to access the TeamCity website. I want to hide TeamCity for team as possible.

Comment: @GongdoGong have you solved this problem?

Comment: @IvanSmetanin unfortunately, no. maybe you can fire TeamCity build by using Github Action, such as: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_review_comment